# Render map as json in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails for my application, and I have a problem with JSON converters.

In my controller, I have:

```
def myObject = [:]
myObject.key = 'value'
render ???
```

what is optimal way to render `myObject` as JSON from the controller?

Comment: I assume `myObject` is a map? The code you posted makes no sense otherwise. If this is the case, instead of `myObject.put("key", "value")`, you can do: `myObject[ 'key' ] = 'value'`

Comment: Adding to tim's point. You can even do myObject.key = 'value'

Comment: @Valeri Maybe that nugget of important information should be in the question?

Comment: Updated the question so it is more understandable, and  includes @uchamp's suggestion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy :

```
render (myObject as JSON)
```

or

```
render ([key: "value"] as JSON)
```

Comment: `render myObject as JSON` would do, no need for the parentheses

Comment: Leaving out the parentheses is fine for simple cases, but it trips you up if you ever try to do `render (something) as JSON` (which parses as `(render something) as JSON` rather than `render (something as JSON)`).  After having been bitten by this once too often I now use the explicit parentheses every time...

Answer (score 1):

Other way is :

```
        render (contentType: 'text/json'){
        array {
            for(f in Person.list()){
                person id: f.id, name: f.name
            }
        }
    }
```

This sample render a list of Persons